# How to contain text within a container that has an image with dynamic size?

Tags: css

Consider this html:

```
<div>
<a href="#" title="image"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/lqikvh05r/black_shirt.jpg" /></a>
<h3>Some text here but if this gets long it will pass the image and not wrap</h3>
</div>
```

So without knowing the image size ahead of time, is there a CSS way to contain the text to as wide as the image and wrap if it gets longer?

Here is a fiddle of the issue -> http://jsfiddle.net/qRGM5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mhhh I don't know if there is a workaround with CSS, but you could try Javascript (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').css('width', $('img').width()+'px');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

No-javascript workaround (you will need image width):

```
<div style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid red;">
    <a href="#" title="image"><img src="http://s9.postimg.org/lqikvh05r/black_shirt.jpg" /></a>
    <h3 style="width: 300px;">Some text here but what if this text gets really long and passed the image</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I know how to use JS to do it as well but just thought there is a CSS way and there really should be because it would be extremely useful.  Setting the width of the containing div to whatever size the image is, is not practical as many times images are user uploaded and there is no way to hardcode a specific width.

Comment: I understand. Maybe you can check image dimension with PHP and apply it to `h3`, and then set `style="display: inline-block"` to your div. Look here: (http://jsfiddle.net/DBwzc/)

Comment: Yeah that is an option but both these options are not ideal and both of them requires inline styles...But since there doesn't seem to be a CSS only solution, I will mark your comment as the correct one. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

i know its probably obvious and maybe not what you're looking for.
but it would work if you were willing to set a max width on the image.

```
#picture img {
max-width:100px;
}
#picture {
max-width:100px;
}
#text{
max-width:inherit;
}

<div id="picture">
<a href="#" title="image">
<img src="http://s9.postimg.org/lqikvh05r/black_shirt.jpg"     /></a>
<h3><div id="text" >Some text here but if this gets long
 it will pass the image and not wrap</div></h3>
```